# Which user is logged in, with likewise and Ubuntu12.4?

Tags: python, users, active-directory, likewise

I need to know which user is logged in my computer but with likewise package installed it does not work.
I've used the following commands
who
users
psutil.get_users()[with python]

in all cases the result is [] empty, nothing

Any tips?

I'm using python3 ubuntu12.4 and psutil 0.51

Comment: I always just use `who` from the CLI..(BASH)

Answer (score 0):

psutil 0.51 is ancient, even versions 1.x are deprecated. You should use some version in the 2.x branch.

Note that you should use psutil.users() instead of the old psutil.get_users() and that Ubuntu repos have version 1.2.1.